# Problems plotting GAM predicted values and GAMM AR1 in the same plot with data

Tags: r, plot, gam

I have ran a GAM with my data and I am plotting the predicted values from the GAM in a graph together with the data points. There are 15 graphs of the same for different areas, and for some of them there is a autocorrelation problem. For these I have run a GAMM AR1 model, and now I want to plot predicted values for these similar to the other areas. Under you will see two graphs, the one to the left are the predicted values from the GAM with confidence intervals, together with the real data. On the right you will see the line from the GAMM AR1.

[image]

As you can see the GAM plot has predicted values, CIs and the "real data" x axis with the data points. The GAMM AR1 has a blue line, with the "GAMM values" on the x axis.

How do I plot predicted values from the GAMM AR1 similar to what I do with the GAM? See data and scripts below.

Data (data frame 'eg'):

```
structure(list(Year = c(1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 
1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 
1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 
1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016), F = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 14, 24, 10, 15, 26, 20, 
15, 19, 13, 18), M = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 27, 40, 35, 39, 19, 30, 42, 42, 39, 56, 50), U = c(100, 
79, 71, 87, 119, 56, 98, 78, 50, 58, 71, 131, 159, 89, 100, 43, 
28, 89, 108, 95, 110, 131, 114, 45, 49, 56, 52, 51, 69, 81, 85, 
60, 54, 46, 54, 57, 1, 5, 8, 5, 0, 1, 1, 5, 8, 2, 0), Tot = c(100, 
79, 71, 87, 119, 56, 98, 78, 50, 58, 71, 131, 159, 89, 100, 43, 
28, 89, 108, 95, 110, 131, 114, 45, 49, 56, 52, 51, 69, 81, 85, 
60, 54, 46, 54, 57, 44, 59, 67, 54, 34, 57, 63, 62, 66, 71, 68
), ratio = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.6875, 2.85714285714286, 1.45833333333333, 
3.9, 1.26666666666667, 1.15384615384615, 2.1, 2.8, 2.05263157894737, 
4.30769230769231, 2.77777777777778), popsize = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-47L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

GAM script and plotting of pred values with CIs and data:

```
m.eg <- gam(Tot~s(Year),family=poisson,data=eg)

YearP=seq(1970,2016,by=1)
meg.pred=predict(m.eg,newdata=data.frame(Year=YearP),type="response",se.fit=T)

plotCI(x=YearP, y=meg.pred$fit,uiw=2*meg.pred$se.fit, type="l",sfrac=0.003,
       ylim=c(40,140),xlim=c(1970,2016),
       col="red",gap=0,lwd=1.6,cex=1.2,las=1, 
       xlab="", ylab="Number of animals")
points(eg$Year,eg$Tot,pch=19,cex=0.9)
```

GAMM AR1 script and plotting of line:

```
m.eg.ar1 <- gamm(Tot~s(Year),family=poisson,correlation = corAR1(form = ~ Year), data=eg)
plot(eg$Year,predict(m.eg),col="white")
lines(eg$Year,predict(m.eg.ar1$gam),col="blue")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Predicting the values for `gamm` is almost the same as for `gam` so you almost had it.
The only difference is that a `gamm` object consists of a `gam` and an `lme` object and the `predict` method only takes `gam` as argument. So you have to specify this in the `predict` call. The code below works for your example:

```
m.eg.ar1 <- gamm(Tot~s(Year),family=poisson,correlation = corAR1(form = ~ Year), data=eg)
megar1.pred=predict(m.eg.ar1$gam,newdata=data.frame(Year=YearP),type="response",se.fit=T)
plotCI(x=YearP, y=megar1.pred$fit,uiw=2*megar1.pred$se.fit, type="l",sfrac=0.003,
       ylim=c(40,140),xlim=c(1970,2016),
       col="red",gap=0,lwd=1.6,cex=1.2,las=1, 
       xlab="", ylab="Number of animals")
points(eg$Year,eg$Tot,pch=19,cex=0.9)
```

[image: Result of gamm with raw data]

Comment: This works, thanks. It remains to see if the AIC of the relationship improves. How do I check the AIC of the new object? The AIC of the original GAM object 'm.eg' is checked with AIC(m.eg), but this doesn't work for 'm.eg.ar1', and not for 'm.eg.ar1$gam'.

Comment: You can get an AIC for gamm with `AIC(m.eg.ar1$lme)` however you cannot compare this AIC to the one obtained for a gam model since gam is fitted by REML and gamm by penalized quasi likelihood... However if autocorrelation is an issue in the first model, it would be enough to check if you tackled the autocorrelation problem with the second model to support using it instead of the first one. This can be done using following command `acf(resid(m.eg.ar1$gam))`.

Comment: I have 5 similar data series I have to deal with in this way, correcting for autocorrelation. Four of the series work fine and it all make sense, but, however, when running the gamm-procedure on the fifth data series I get this error message: iteration 1
iteration 2
Error in recalc.corAR1(object[[i]], conLin) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)

Comment: This is probably nlme not being able to fit the correlation term. I cannot tell how this happened without looking at the data. Maybe you should ask a new question to resolve the issue. Comparing the data of the fifth data series with one of the previous ones might help in finding the problem.